# LLVM assembly: assign integer constant to register

Tags: assembly, integer, constants, llvm

I'm writing [a compiler](https://github.com/mildred/Lysaac) that uses LLVM as a backend, and my compiler generates the following LLVM assembly code

```
@0 = private constant [25 x i8] c"Hello World to %dntegers\00"

declare void @printf (i8*, i32)

define void @main () {
  %1 = getelementptr [25 x i8]* @0, i32 0, i32 0
  %2 = 1
  tail call void @printf(i8* %1, i32 %2)
  ret void
}
```

But I get the following error:

```
c.ll:8:8: error: expected instruction opcode
  %2 = 1
       ^
```

The documentation shows [examples like that](http://llvm.org/docs/LangRef.html#undefvalues) though.

Do you know how to get this to work? Currently, I'm using instead:

```
  %2 = add i32 0, 1 ; FIXME
```

Comment: Why do you want to bind a constant value to a name? Just use the constant in place, as in `tail call void @printf(i8* %1, i31 1)`. Btw., are you generating IR as a text? What for?

Comment: Because this is simpler for the code generator. I'm using textual IR because I don't have easy access to C/C++ libs from the language I am using.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

See the LLVMdev discussion ["How to assign a constant to a register?"](http://markmail.org/message/usg36tuzwebdcmcu#query:+page:1+mid:gmtaeqtxlm2k3zim+state:results) As pointed out there by Duncan Sands:

> let me say that in general doing this is pointless. Due to SSA form, if %x is set to 5 you can't set it to something else later. Thus everywhere that you use %x you might as well just directly use 5 there instead. A common situation is that you have a register %x, and due to performing optimizations you discover that in fact %x will always have the value 5. You can use RAUW (aka the replaceAllUsesWith method) to replace %x with 5 everywhere.

The thread did generate a couple alternatives to directly using the constant:

- Use `alloca` to get a pointer, store to it, then load the value as needed.
- Create a global pointing to the constant, then load that value as needed.

Someone pointed out that the `alloca` approach will end up using a register after optimization.

Regardless, using the constant directly as suggested by @SK-logic seems to be the cleanest solution.

Comment: Finally, I work around my code generator to avoid the creation of a register here.